# Strings manipulation and variables in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, wget

I try to download something with wget using `for` loop in `bash` script:

When i'm not using variables everything work fine, when i assign it into variables i have `500 server error`. This is strange for me, because this is only copy-paste.

What i'm trying to do is take number from loop `i` and paste it into body.

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..5}
do
    STR="some_static_stuff_before"$i"some_static_suff_after"
    echo $STR
    wget -O ready/page$i.aspx --header="Host: www.something.com" --header="Pragma: no-cache" --header="Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8" --header="Accept-Language: en-en" --header="Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" --header="Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" --header="Origin: http://something.com" --header="Connection: keep-alive" --header="User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.73.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.1 Safari/537.73.11" --header="Referer: http://www.something.com/something.aspx" --header="Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=u5cmt0figi4bvs40a30gnwsa; __utma=20059042.38323768.1389369038.1389710153.1389780868.6; __utmb=20059042.2.10.1389780868; __utmc=20059042; __utmz=20059042.1389627823.2.2.utmcsr=something.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/something.aspx" --post-data='"$STR"' http://something.com/something.aspx
done
```

And when i paste object directly to `--post-data` there is no problem with download content.

I've tried `--post-data= "/"$STR/""` and `--post-data='"$STR"'` and still not working.

Comment: Why don't you do simply --post-data="$STR" ?

Comment: Why did you try --post-data= "/"$STR/""?  Is that a typo?  Did you mean --post-data= "\"$STR\""?

Comment: Yes, there was a typo. But didn't fix a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You single-quoted the variable reference (in addition to double-quoting it), which prevents substitution of the variable value.

Instead of

```
--post-data='"$STR"'
```

use

```
--post-data="$STR"
```

Comment: Didn't  work. Still the same 500 error. This dont make any sense to me

Comment: @Kuba: Does the variable value itself need to contain double quotes? If so, try `--post-data="\"$STR\""`.